# Elm: Chain Http.send and Http.get

Tags: elm

I'm (a beginner) having a type issue trying to chain to HTTP calls in my Elm application:

```
Http.send ... `Task.andThen` (\_ -> Http.get ...)
```

This is because `Http.send` return type is `Task RawError Response`,
and `Http.get` return type is `Task Error value`.

Any suggestion on how to make them work together?

EDIT1:

Maybe `mapError` is the solution?

EDIT2:

I'm not saying that the first call failed, I'm sure it works. It is the compiler that doesn't validate my code:

```
The right argument of `andThen` is causing a type mismatch.

135│     Http.send Http.defaultSettings config
136│>      `Task.andThen` (\_ -> Http.get (Json.Decode.list userJsonDecoder) "http://localhost:3000/")

`andThen` is expecting the right argument to be a:

    Http.Response -> Task Http.RawError a

But the right argument is:

    Http.Response -> Task Http.Error (List User)
```

Comment: Can you show are complete example, including the exact error message?

Comment: @SørenDebois Yes, I just edided my message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way to map a `RawError` to an `Error` and then you can use [`Task.mapError`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Task#mapError) as you suggested in your first edit. One possibility would be:

```
rawErrorToError : Http.RawError -> Http.Error
rawErrorToError rawError =
  case rawError of
    Http.RawTimeout -> Http.Timeout
    Http.RawNetworkError -> Http.NetworkError

Http.send Http.defaultSettings config
|> Task.mapError rawErrorToError
`Task.andThen` ...
```

Comment: It seems the right technical answer but I decided to only use the more generic `Http.send` method in my code for consistency.